# Initialize/create `constexpr` array from `static const` C-array

Tags: arrays, c++11

I have an array of `const struct MyType[];`, declared in a C-header and defined in the accompanying C-file -- whose signature cannot be changed easily. I want to provide a `constexpr` cpp interface to this database and are looking for a way to convert/adopt/use the const array inside a constexpr context.

Template magic maybe? But the indirection would still be present, and the initialization-time of the used array is not well-defined...

Once proof-of-concept I had was providing the properties of the database via a number of `std::integral_constant<T,value>`. But this relied on a generated cpp-duplication of the C-database. Not efficient, cumbersome, and fragile as hell!

Any tips, ideas or devastating cites from the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable marked `constexpr` must be fully computable at *compile* time, not *link* time. So if your array is defined in a `.cpp` file, separately from the declaration - it cannot be `constexpr`. No need to quote the standard here, it's very simple.

(I'm ignoring your mention of using .c files, that's not really part of the question I assume.)

Comment: Ignoring C headers at least does not change facts. C had no symbolic constants, `const` has different semantics than in C++. It should be very clear that it's not possible from what `constexpr` means.

Comment: @Olaf: Like I said, I'm assuming OP didn't really mean to talk about C at all.